# TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function: given when trying to use Material UI in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEldy.png)

I receive the following error message when using npm start on my project.
Only started occurring aftering installing Material UI and Emotion, it is fixed if I don't import any packages it from it.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "howler": "^2.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10"
  },
  "main": "/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.82.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1"
  },
  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build2": "webpack --mode=development"
  }
```

Import statements in App.js

```
import { Autocomplete } from '@mui/material';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
```

Function using Autocomplete from MUI

```
function SearchBar() {
    

    //get list of songs here
    var nameList = getSongsList();
    
    
    function handleChange() {

    }

    return (
        //old search box that worked fine, but wanted to upgrade
        //<input type="search" className="searchBox" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search here" />
        <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            id="searchBar"
            options={nameList}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search" />}
        />
    );

}
```

I've tried un-installing and re-installing MUI, Emotion, Webpack, Webpack-cli, etc. nothing seems to fix this error. Please let me know if you need more info, this is my first React project so I am learning a lot as I go.
[Compiled code snippet of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC8gG.png)

Comment: Could you provide the compiled code snippet that raises the error?

Comment: @YuLing Sorry, updated the post to include the image of that. Couldn't add it to this comment.

Comment: I cannot determine what happened when webpack processes the stylis's exports without the webpack config or the final bundle file. What I can tell is that your Emotion tries to use a function called `middleware` exported by `stylis` but it seems like the webpack didn't process it properly. You may provide a Pastebin link to your bundle file so I can try to find out what happened.

Comment: @YuLing https://pastebin.com/unqcVeSJ

Comment: It looks the content of the bundle is incomplete. I don't see the related code in it.